# Thin Client Server Configuration

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, server-configuration, thin-client

I have 15 t5500 HP thin client and i am looking for Server configuration which can handle upto 20 thin clients.

Usage: Internet (browser), MS office, Simple multimedia (Movies, Songs).

No Games, No CPU intensive programs (like photoshop or visual studio etc).

I need to know a Normal configuration for the Server.

My thoughts:
8GB RAM, Core i5,500GB Hard disk,Windows Server 2008.

Does 1 licence of Windows server 2008 supports 15-20 thin clients?

Thank  you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little Complex of a question, but from my expeirence for 20 users on a windows 2008 system you will need at least 16 GB of RAM.  My envirnment when I used physical machines I used Dell PowerEdge 1950's with Dual Xeon E5410s (4 Cores @ 2.33GHz), 500GB is more than what I used but that is definitly something not to skimp on if you can get away with it.

1 Windows Sever 2008 Cal comes with 5 user CALs but you will need to purchase either user or machine CALs.  Difference either each user will need a CAL, which will follow them or a CAL for each of the thin clients and it doesn't matter how many users you have logon as long as they are using one of those devices.  You will need to install the TS Licensing Server feature as well and point your TS server to that installation.  That is where you would install the purchased licenses

Now a little practical matter, multimedia does not work well across an RDP connection even while on the same LAN.  You can get it to work ok but if all 20 clients are streaming video it will become very choppy to almost unwatchable.  The hardware that you are wanting to use, yes its possible but I doubt very highly that you will achieve a very usable environment for your users.  Now if you went with Windows 2003 Server x64 you could get away with the hardware you wanted.  The reason is because of how Microsoft designed the user enviornment in 2008 they separated the memory for each user session while in 2003 and 2000 the sessions shared some of the memory.

Comment: Thank you, that will give some startup.